# How do I nest lists properly?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, nesting

I want my list as shown in the second example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures), but when I implement my own code in the same manner, I'm not achieving the same result. Here is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]

    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

Why do these lists begin on the same line instead of beeing indented properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have *nothing* as part of the first item. If you want an "empty" item and have the nested list indented, set "nothing":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
    \item 
    \item 
  \end{enumerate}
  \item \mbox{}% Set "nothing" in the form of an empty box
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
    \item 
    \item 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that solved a problem that have puzzled me for a few days!